# How to watch all the folders of a specific name under a parent directory with FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I have a directory structure like the following where csv files may be added to any of the sub-directories. (The business logic is that order files firstly will be save under "Vendor" folder, and after being checked, they will be moved to "Processed" folders.)

I want to only monitor folders called "Processed". For example, if there are files added to "Processed" folder, I would like to get notified and do something in the callback methods. If files are added under "Vendor" folder, I want to ignore them. How should I configure FileSystemWatcher to achieve this?

[image]

This is what I've got now.

```
public static void Watch()
{
   FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
   watcher.Path = path; //here is the path of the "Order" folder;
   watcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
   watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;         
}

private static void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   //do something when there are new files added to the watched directory
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileSystemWatcher` has a property called `IncludeSubdirectories`, When true, `IncludeSubdirectories` is recursive through the entire sub tree, not just the immediate child directories.

So an example would be something like this (modified [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netcore-3.1#examples) example):

```
private static void Watch(string watch_folder)
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    watcher.Path = watch_folder;
    /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
       the renaming of files or directories. */
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
       | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

    // Add event handlers.
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

    // Begin watching.
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

// Define the event handlers.
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
}

private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
}
```

### See also

- [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netcore-3.1), MSDN

## Update

This is a small console example on how to filter notifications to only react to the `Processed` folders based on @MickyD comment:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Order");
            Console.WriteLine(path);
            FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(path);
            fileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            fileSystemWatcher.Changed += FileSystemWatcher_Changed;
            fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            Process.GetCurrentProcess().WaitForExit();
            fileSystemWatcher.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void FileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Name.Contains("Processed"))
            Console.WriteLine("Processed folder has changed");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen this example that you provided. It doesn't allow me only monitor certain directories. How do I only monitor sub-directories with name "Processed"?

Comment: Note that by specifying `IncludeSubdirectories = true` when the `Path` is say _"Orders"_, FSW has the potential to return "changes" for the `Vendor` folders.  You might need to filter those out on the `OnChanged`.  Consider adding a filter. +1 regardless.  Also, FSW doesn't catch _all_ events as the OS can discard some during busy periods.  Using a FSW with subdirectories might increase the risk.  It _may_ be better to have separate FSWs for each `Processed` folder though that is probably a larger design issue for the OP.

Comment: @Grace From what i've seen from the `FileSystemWatcher` API, there isn't a method specific for that, but if you have a specific file type, maybe a filter could do the job?

Comment: @MickyD You're right, if the number of `Processed` folders is known before the FSW starts.

Comment: I have edited your answer a bit, hope you don't mind.  Be careful about posting code from elsewhere without citing it.

Comment: The files that might be added to the sub-directories are all csv files, so probably filtering by file type is not suitable in this situation.

Comment: @Grace _"...so probably filtering by file type is not suitable in this situation..."_ - surely it is still beneficial to the application and _nice_ to the OS to continue to filter by `"*.csv"` as it cuts down on _noise_ and noise hurts FSW